# PHP - Uploading multiple photos to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, upload

So I found some code that works perfectly to upload a file to a directory, but I have been struggling for days trying to simply upload multiple photos at once to a database. I need some help trying to figure it out since I've come up empty on all these tutorials...

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>File:</p>
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" >
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here's my database info (a test db):

```
|| idtest (AI INT) || nameTesting (varchart 50) || testing (longblob)
```

Here' my PHP so far:

```
<?php
  //Connect to DB
    $conn = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root');

    if (!$conn){
      die("Could Not Connect to MySQL!");
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db("test")){
      die("Could Not Open Database:" . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "<p>Connected</p>";

  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $name);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$f] < 2000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$f] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$f] . "<br>";
      } else {
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $name)){
          echo "<p>File Already Exists</p>";
        } else {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], "upload/" . uniqid() . "_" . $name);
        }
      }
    } else {
      $error =  "Invalid file";
    }
  }
?>
```

What my ultimate goal is is to create a dynamic page creator which includes a gallery. So I'm looking for the best way to upload multiple photo's for each unique page in one go an unlimited quantity. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought of possibly doing what you are doing, but instead of moving the photos to your database, just store the link to the directory of the file in the database. (This will also stop your database from exploding)

e.g. something along the lines of ..

```
 else 
 {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], "upload/" . uniqid() . "_" . $name);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO filelocation (FID,filelocation) VALUES (DEFAULT,'{$filepath}');  
 }
```

then you can just select the file path location dynamically when you need to

Comment: ah that might be better indeed! and then create directories specific to each unique page, right? how would I go about doing that?

Comment: dynamically creating pages is another question I think you would want to use something like copy($defaultpage,$newpage)

Comment: and however you name it your could refer to it by the name of the page using REQUEST_URI http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: and you could name the file name the same as the file name so that when you are on that page it will reffer to the file so that your code could be standard across all pages, and then when you copy a page you only need to rename it and the code will work based on its file name (hope this is helping)

Comment: ok I don't quite get it. So in order to create a dynamic page generator with photos, I want to drop photos into a newly created unique directory which will be linked to when the new page gets created... I link this new directory's name to the page by storing the link name into the database, so it will search the directory. am i missing anything?

Comment: I hope I'm understanding your question correctly, but you want to create new .php pages "create a dynamic page creator" if I have understood this correctly the way I would go about this would be 
1.) upload your files save it as $name in a set of folders 1-10 and save the path to these files e.g. folder1/$name folder2/$name
then create your new php page copy the default and rename it $name.php, then inside this page you would refer to your photo files by folder1/REQUEST_URI folder2/REQUEST_URI (abbreviated)
Put me on the spot but that is "a" way to solve what I think you are trying to achieve

Comment: or bang all the files uploaded in one folder and name them $name[i] and then refer to them in the newly created page as folder/REQUEST_URI[i]

Comment: aight thanks a lot man i really needed this help!!! I'll let you know if I got it running! Thanks again!

Comment: Hey man, so I haven't got anything running yet :/ My files won't move :/

Comment: I thought you said your above code work for uploading the files to the server?

Comment: I recently got it to work eventually. it uploaded to a directory, but now i wanted to create a subdirectory everytime I upload, and have multiple files upload into that newly created directory. I got it to work now, and it works well!

Comment: Awesome! if it is public you will have to give me a link, sounds impressive

Comment: if it's possible I could email or chat you the code if you're interested?